# Keep lexical context in prototype of types

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to append a closure to the prototype of `Number`, in TypeScript, but, after compiled, `this` is bounded to the `window` object instead of applying to the number from which the method has been called.

```
interface Number {
    pad(s: number): string;
}

Number.prototype.pad = (size: number) => {
  var s: string = String(this);
  while (s.length < (size || 2)) {
    s = "0" + s;
  }
  return s;
};
```

This should work fine, but `this` becomes bounded when translated:

```
var _this = this;
Number.prototype.pad = function (size) {
    var s = String(_this);
    while (s.length < (size || 2)) {
        s = "0" + s;
    }
    return s;
};
```

I'm searching for hours across StackOverflow and TypeScript documentation and didn't find a way to unbound `this`. What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> this becomes bounded when translated

Don't use an arrow function

```
Number.prototype.pad = function(size: number)  {
```

Comment: Why do they get bounded? I have found the same "issue" sometimes, and I would appreciate a deeper explanation.

Comment: `Why do they get bounded` There are use cases where this is desireable *especially* for `this`. Here is a video that presents these use cases : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tvocUcbCupA

Comment: Thanks +1, too bad the "fat arrow" syntax couldn't be used as @Marcelo Camargo, supposed.

Comment: To be honest the number of times *one wants this to be lexically bound* far exceeds the number of times one wants to have a `this` determined by the calling context

Answer (score 0):

Would it be better to use a class

```
export class Number {

public pad(size: number) {
    var s: string = String(this);
    while (s.length < (size || 2)) {
        s = "0" + s;
    }
    return s;
};
}


//compiled javascript

define(["require", "exports"], function(require, exports) {
   var Number = (function() {
       function Number() {}
       Number.prototype.pad = function(size) {
           var s = String(this);
           while (s.length < (size || 2)) {
               s = "0" + s;
       }
        return s;
    };;
    return Number;
})();
exports.Number = Number;
});
```